# how can I use awk to search ahead in a file and delete lines if they match the previous 3 lines

Tags: awk, duplicates

Because of pagination I have a file that duplicates the heading lines if the data cannot be printed on the current page. For example:
H

```
eading
data1
data2
data3 ...
```

then at the bottom of the page:

```
NEW Heading
Heading line2
Heading line3
; no more room on this page so a new page is generated and duplicates above -
NEW Heading
Heading line2
Heading line3
```

So basically I need to store 3 lines, look ahead 3 lines and if they match then delete the duplicate 3 lines from the file

Comment: is your troublesome file the output of an `*roff` process that you control? Good cluk.

Answer (score 0):

AWK can't do kind look ahead stuff. AWK is stream oriented.

file example:

```
$ cat example
Heading
data1
data2
data3
NEW Heading
Heading line2
Heading line3
NEW Heading
Heading line2
Heading line3
```

Not clean AWK (+sort) hack solution using associative array:

```
$ awk '{ if ( arr[$0]=="" ) arr[$0]=NR; } END { for (i in arr) print(arr[i] " " i); }' example | sort -n | awk -F'^[0-9]+ ' '{ print($NF); }'
Heading
data1
data2
data3
NEW Heading
Heading line2
Heading line3
```

1. awk assigns line number of first line occurrence to associative array. In the end it prints line number and line separated by space.
2. sort sorts output in numeric order
3. awk splits per regex number with space and outputs original line

---

For clean GAWK solution (with using sort inside) you may study:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html#Array-Sorting-Functions